# Sharepoint 2013 Contact integration with Outlook

Tags: list, 2013, outlook, contacts

We're trying to move away from the whole public folders thing...we have a fair few contacts in these folders at the moment however (about 5000). I have connected my contact list to Outlook and copied a few across as a sort of tester. This worked fine, however the address field is empty on the sharepoint site where as it's full in the outlook version of the contact card?

I then discovered that the address isn't displayed on the site unless the address "type" is set to business. The vast majority of our contacts have the address listed under "home". Is there a way to change which type of address sharepoint displays?

Cheers,
Robb